# is anyone solved animation error in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, fadein, fadeout

Error in my code is, I add condition to run a JavaScript function only one time but when I add if else logic web page can open all sections

here is my code logic:

```
let count = 0;
window.addEventListener('scroll', fade);
function fade()
{
  if (count < 1)
  {
    let animation=document.querySelectorAll('.fade');
    for (let i=0; i<animation.length; i++)
    {
      let windowheight=window.innerHeight;
      let top=animation[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if (top < windowheight)
      {
      animation[i].classList.add('visible');
      }
      else
      {
      animation[i].classList.remove('visible');
      }    
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return ;
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to handle the event once,

window.addEventListener('scroll', fade, {once: true});

You can safely remove count variable and if...else.

Comment: can you add and remove from my code to better understanding plz?

Comment: hi! man its not working can you guide me plz

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).